# Running single keycloak instance in two different https port in Keycloak Quarkus Distribution

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-connect

Migrating from Keycloak wildfly to Keycloak Quarkus.

In my previous config in standalone-ha.xml am exposing the my keycloak process in two different ports
using https-listener

```
<https-listener name="https-1" socket-binding="https-1" proxy-address-forwarding="true" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable-http2="true" verify-client="REQUESTED" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"/>

<https-listener name="https-2" socket-binding="https-2" proxy-address-forwarding="true" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable-http2="true" verify-client="REQUESTED" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"/>
```

Want to know, how this config can be migrated to Keycloak Quarkus distribution.

Thanks in advance for the response.